# filling an array with array_pad

Tags: php, arrays

I am currently working on a site where I have an array that must contain 8 values.

I generate a random number and write it into my array, after that i would liek to check if this number was infact 8 character long. If this was not the case it should be filled with leading zero's.

Here is the code i am using

```
$number=rand(0,255);

// convert the number to binary and store it as an array
$states=str_split(decbin($number),1);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($states,true).'</pre>';

// in case the number is not 8 bit long make it an 8 bit number using array_pad

if(count($states)<8){
   $states = array_pad($states,count($states)-8,"0");
}
```

The problem is now that it never fills up the array even if the array only consists of 3 or 4 entrys.

Thanks for the help.

Edit :Thanks to everyone for awnsering so quickly the solution provided by Suresh Kamrushi is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
 $states = array_pad($states,count($states)-8,"0");
```

Try like this:

```
$number=rand(0,255);

// convert the number to binary and store it as an array
$states=str_split(decbin($number),1);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($states,true).'</pre>';

// in case the number is not 8 bit long make it an 8 bit number using array_pad

if(count($states)<8){
   $states = array_pad($states,8,"0");
}
print_r($states);
```

PHP fiddle:  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/a1d-m97

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you don't need `count($states) - 8`:

```
$states = array_pad($states, -8, "0");
```

Which will pad the array to a size of 8, with leading zeroes

Answer (score 1):

For [array_pad](https://www.php.net/array_pad) the second argument is the size you want the array to be, not the number of items you want to add to it.

So just do:

```
if(count($states)<8){
   $states = array_pad($states,8,"0");
}
```

Or, as `array_pad` has no effect if your array is already big enough, you don't even need the `if(count($states)<8)` part.